# Why Unity includes the Editor directories in build

Tags: unity-game-engine, build

When I try to build my game, Unity includes the scripts contained in my **Editor** directories. This implies the build to fail because *Unity.Editor* is not accessible during the build. I'm using *Unity 2020.1.6f1*, how can I solve this problem ?

This is the type of error i'm getting durring the build:

> Assets\Scripts\Editor\EnemyLootEditor.cs(7,32): error CS0246: The type
> or namespace name 'Editor' could not be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)

Theses errors doesn't occur when the game is lauched in *Editor Mode*.

This is a picture of my **Scripts** folder that contains all of my code files, including my **Editor** files:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Thomas says, yes, you have to check that your Editor files are stored in the Editor directory, and use the compiler directive when you use them.

BUT this problem seems more related with Assembly Definition files, check this related [link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/player-build-error-with-editor-folders.556864/).

> Are you using assembly definition files? They don't respect Editor
> folders. You need to add Editor asmdefs.

Summarizing, if you have one .asmdef file in your project, and you are using Editor scripts, you need to **ALSO** have a **.asmdef file for your Editor scripts**.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine now ! So, to make it short, I had to create a new *assembly definition* file in my **Editor** folder:  the *EditorAssembly* file. Then I add my *GameAssembly* file to the references of the *EditorAssembly* and finally, I added the *UNITY_EDITOR* constraint to it.

Comment: one don't has to use the compilation constraint "UNITY_EDITOR". selecting only "Editor" AND deselecting "Any" under Platforms should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Files stored in a folder named "Editor" do not included in builds. [(see special folder names in unity)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html)

If you make calls to editor code in "regular" script files you have to surround this code with the `UNITY_EDITOR` compiler directive:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
// will not be present in build
[...]
#endif
```

Comment: or put your files in Editor folder

Comment: @Lotan That's the problem, these scripts **are** in a **Editor** directory. I know they should not be part of the build but it is somehow what happens.

Comment: @DeWolfMaxime do you have any assembly file?

Comment: @Lotan Yes, I have an assembly file at the base of my *Scripts* folder and my *Editor* folder is in it. This could explain my bugs ?